# image quarternion FFT generally better results?

Tags: c++, complexity-theory, fft

Its just only question is FFT of image(represent like quarternions) generally better than standart repres.: R;G;B.?-3 matrix of real numbers...

if yes, is there some way how to impleement cooley tukey code of 1D FFT with quarternion?maybe in Eigen  c++ lib.?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see the utility in mapping RGB(A) to a quaternion. What would the multiplication of quaternions imply for RGB? How would you interpret the fact that multiplication is [not commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Noncommutativity_of_multiplication)? The fact that elegant, abstract algebras exist, doesn't mean that they reflect *reality*.

That said, [this paper](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mperkows/CAPSTONES/Quaternion/00960426.pdf) has actually defined a QFT with a spectral interpretation! It uses the R,G,B values for the i, j, k components, and sets the 'real' component to (0).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I may undestand, so  the 3D matrix will be with same effect....